# Trying to write a unit test for the method which sets ownership

Tags: python

**python

```
def set_permissions(file):
    if not os.path.exists(file):
       print("file doesn't exists")
    return False
    path_1= /opt/var
    path_2 = /opt/setup
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
       uid = f.readline()
       gid = f.readline()
    os.chown(path_1,int(uid),int(gid))
    os.chown(path_1,int(uid),int(gid))
    return True
```

**

I am trying to write unit test case for above method

```
@patch('os.path.exists',return_value=True)
def test_set_permissions(self, *args):
   result = set_permissions('example.txt')
   self.assertequals(True, result)
```

for this I am trying to unittest case in a way that it should write True if file exists, But I see an error saying module os doesn't have the attribute chown. Please help. Thanks in advance